# making independent matplotlib plots in same figure without GridSpec?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

i would like to juxtapose two separate plots in matplotlib in the same figure. each part of the plot calls `subplot` and i would like their axes to be independent. example: i want to juxtapose two plots, one which makes a 1x3 subplot and another that makes a 2x2 subplot, in the same figure:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

def plot_A():
    # make a set of subplots here...
    plt.subplot(1, 3, 1)
    plt.subplot(1, 3, 2)
    plt.subplot(1, 3, 3)    

def plot_B():
    # make a set of independent subplots here
    plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
    plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
    plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)
    plt.subplot(2, 2, 4)

def make_fig():
    width = 6.
    height = 5.
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(width, height))
    ratio = height / width
    ax1 = fig.add_axes([.03 * ratio, .03, .9 * ratio, .9])
    # make plot A
    plot_A()
    ax1 = fig.add_axes([.03 * ratio, .01, .9 * ratio, .9 / 2.5])
    # make plot B below plot A in the figure, with
    # space constraints given by fig.add_axes
    plot_B()
    plt.show()

make_fig()
```

this doesn't work because the subplot calls in `plot_B` override ones in `plot_A`. i know that gridspec can be used to make a single layout that contains both, but i can't use this. plot_A and plot_B might be functions that are in separate modules, and can be called to make standalone figures independent of `make_fig()`.

**update:** the solution is to use multiple gridspecs with `gridspec.update` to position them in different spots in the figure.

Comment: Curious why you don't want to use `plt.GridSpec`, it seems like exactly the right tool here.

Comment: @mwaskom: because gridspec forces me to break code modularity by making a global gridspec that takes into account both ``plot_A()`` and ``plot_B()``. but these two functions make subplots that are also used to make standalone figures of just A or just B. with gridspec i would have to make a new function that reproduces the code of ``plot_A()`` and ``plot_B()``

Comment: You can use multiple GridSpec objects in the same figure so I'm not sure what you mean there.

Comment: @mwaskom: you are right i didn't know that ``update`` allows you to position independent gridspecs in same figure in different spots this solves it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your subplots are sharing the same space.

Choose subplots that don't overlap and you should be fine:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
def plot1():
    pl.subplot(3,3,1); pl.plot(1);
    pl.subplot(3,3,2); pl.plot(2);
    pl.subplot(3,3,3); pl.plot(3);
def plot2():
    pl.subplot(3,2,3); pl.plot(4);
    pl.subplot(3,2,4); pl.plot(4);
    pl.subplot(3,2,5); pl.plot(4);
    pl.subplot(3,2,6); pl.plot(4);

plot1()
plot2()
pl.show()
```

Another alternative:

```
def plot1b():
    pl.subplot(3,6,(1,2)); pl.plot(1);
    pl.subplot(3,6,(3,4)); pl.plot(2);
    pl.subplot(3,6,(5,6)); pl.plot(3);
def plot2b():
    pl.subplot(3,6,(7,9)); pl.plot(4);
    pl.subplot(3,6,(10,12)); pl.plot(4);
    pl.subplot(3,6,(13,15)); pl.plot(4);
    pl.subplot(3,6,(16,18)); pl.plot(4);

plot1b()
plot2b()
pl.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

the correct answer as pointed out by @mwaskom is to use multiple gridspecs and use `gridspec.update` to position them in different parts of the figure.